# Can Ubuntu 12.04 be run in P4 Compaq?

Tags: software-recommendation

Can I run Ubuntu 12.04 on P4 3.06 Ghz . I am currently using Windows 7 with no Aero Features. I have no Graphics Card and a 16 MB video card.

Comment: I ran 12.04 on a PIII for a while, but I recommend that you use [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

> Can I run Ubuntu 12 on P4 3.06 GHz?

Yes, why not?

> I am currently using Windows 7 with no Aero Features.
>   I have no Graphics Card and a 16 mb video card.

Ehm, You have none yet you have one?

I am **guessing** you mean you have no dedicated (plug in) graphics card, but that you have an on-board 16 MB graphics card.  16 MB is not much by today's standards, but there is no reason why that would stop you from running Ubuntu.

Comment: The graphics chip might be an issue. Such old graphics cards are often no longer supported by the proprietary drivers, and with open source drivers onboard chips are hardly fast enough to give an acceptable user experience with a 3D-only desktop like Gnome 3 or Unity. I agree with Mitch above, who recommends Xubuntu. This can run without Compositing (aka desktop effects) and also requires quite a bit less RAM than Ubuntu (Xubuntu is usable with as little as 512 MB RAM).

Answer (score 0):

You CAN run ubuntu 12.04 on P4. You can try to run in 2D, but you can expect some troubles with 2D stability.

I recommend to fall down to xfce or gnome desktop, ideally, use Xubuntu distribution.

If you like to use Ubuntu, you SHOULD absolutely maximize your RAM. I would recommend 2GB or more, depend on what you want to run.